# Pandas DataFrame constructor takes list input?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

The pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) for the DataFrame constructor lists the following argument types for the data argument: numpy ndarray (structured or homogeneous), dict, or DataFrame. Yet it clearly accepts a list of lists (see below). I'm relatively new to pandas and just running through a bunch of tests/examples. Does pandas generally accept python lists in place of ndarrays?

```
import pandas as pd
DF_From_List_Input = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])  #works fine!
```

Comment: At risk of over-generalizing, you might think of a numpy array as a generalization of a list of lists and a pandas dataframe as a generalization of a dictionary of lists.  Hence, because you can create a dataframe from a numpy array, it makes sense you could do it from a list of lists.  However, you don't automatically label the columns that way, whereas you do if you create from a dictionary where the keys become the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Pandas generally accepts Python lists in place of ndarrays.  Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L255) for the DataFrame class, there's an explicit check for this, currently on line 255, followed by logic for creating a DataFrame.

```
elif isinstance(data, (list, types.GeneratorType)):
```

Anecdotally, I've never run into any issues passing a list of lists to the DataFrame constructor.